# Unexpected Process.Start Behaviour in Azure WorkerRole

Tags: azure

I'm having some strange behaviour.

Basically, my code runs fine on my local machine and when I login with a remote desktop to the service, I can run the exe no problem from the command line with the exact same arguments I give it in C#. It works perfectly.

What I'm wondering, is if there are any restrictions or permissions that prevent the exe from being run within an Azure WorkerRole? Or maybe there is something wrong in the code that is preventing it from running properly in a WorkerRole, but only on Azure?

- *The exe does not redirect any stdout or stderr so I can't read any output when there's an error. This also occurs on my local.*
- The exe is set to copy to the application's build directory on azure. The exe exists at the path specified (I've tried File.Exists there and for where the pdf is, just to make sure)
- I've tried setting `startInfo.CreateNoWindow` to `true` to see if I can view the process running within remote desktop, but I can't. I assume the WorkerRole and remote desktop are different users on the machine.

Here's my code:

```
LocalResource tempStorage = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("TempStorage");
string tempDir = tempStorage.RootPath;
string tempName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
string tempFile = Path.Combine(tempDir, tempName + ".pdf");
string saveFile = tempName + ".html";
string exeDir = Path.Combine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("RoleRoot") + @"\", @"approot\Resources\");
File.WriteAllBytes(tempFile, fileBytes);

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine(exeDir, "pdf2htmlEX.exe");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.WorkingDirectory = exeDir;
//startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = String.Format("--zoom 1.5 --dest-dir \"{0}\" \"{1}\" \"{2}\"", tempDir, tempFile, saveFile);
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

using (Process proc = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    proc.WaitForExit(30000);
}
// saveFile does not exist here or any time after the process exists
```

Using this project's exe. It's great: https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX

**Edit:** Found some log information...

```
Faulting application name: pdf2htmlEX.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x520bb881
Faulting module name: pdf2htmlEX.exe, version: 0.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x520bb881
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x0013a6e4
Faulting process id: 0x9cc
Faulting application start time: 0x01ceaf4109e78f34
Faulting application path: C:\Resources\directory\96bf7ddee08d45a8883fe2a603131842.WorkerRole.TempStorage\pdf2htmlEX.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Resources\directory\96bf7ddee08d45a8883fe2a603131842.WorkerRole.TempStorage\pdf2htmlEX.exe
Report Id: 48260a60-1b34-11e3-93ef-00155d4334a7
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

The process halts after preprocessing all the pages, then fails while working. If I run "DebugView" I get:

```
[1356] Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.
[1356] Error - 
[1356] RtlWerpReportException failed with status code :-1073283067. Will try to launch the process directly
[1356]
```

Maybe this is a bug with the application? (maybe writing to memory it shouldn't be) I still don't understand why this only fails in a WorkerRole.

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Comment: Yeah, I did and there was nothing. So I'm going blind. I just learned this, but I think it may be because the process [creates intermediate files](https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX/issues/198#issuecomment-24138509). It might be writing these files to the working directory (which is probably not allowed). I'm going to do a test tonight and see if that's the case (by copying the exe to a local resource). If so, I'll update the question to reflect the answer I find in order to make it more general to other people.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a couple different approaches to troubleshooting this.

1. Procmon.  It will show you if you are getting access denied trying to write temporary files somewhere.
2. Attach WinDBG to pdf2htmlEX.exe and see if it is throwing any exceptions.

The trick with #2 is getting WinDBG attached to a process running within Azure is tricky.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/26/azuretools-the-diagnostic-utility-used-by-the-windows-azure-developer-support-team.aspx for a quick and easy way to get Procmon and WinDBG on the Azure VM, and a way to attach WinDBG to the process.